# php add to array x times

Tags: php, arrays, oscommerce

I have modified a dimensions/shipping calculator and almost got it working as i require except i have hit a hurdle that i can not find a solution too.

what I need is to pass

```
 $b->add_inner_box($inner_L,$inner_W,$inner_D);
```

x number of times (set buy a cycle value and $count loop)

this is passed to

```
public function add_inner_box($l,$w,$h) {
    if ($l > 0 && $w > 0 && $h > 0) {
        $this -> inner_boxes[] = array(
            "dimensions" => $this -> sort_dimensions($l,$w,$h),
            "packed" => false
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have looked at arr.push and other options but don`t think these will work in my situation, as you can probably tell i am a novice and could do with some guidance as to add the $b->add_inner_box to the array x times

if I use

```
$b->add_inner_box($inner_L,$inner_W,$inner_D);
$b->add_inner_box($inner_L,$inner_W,$inner_D);
$b->add_inner_box($inner_L,$inner_W,$inner_D);
```

within the script it works but this will not work in my aplication.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming. What you want is called looping and you have some choices: for, while, foreach. Start using http://php.net/manual/en/ as your reference point.

Comment: `while($count--) {$b->add_inner_box(...);}`

Comment: Can you be specific as to why "_will not work in my aplication_"?

Comment: @ vp_arth  while($count--) {$b->add_inner_box(...);} appears to work but only for the value of $count it does not cycle... not sure if a need a for each loop adding ... is it okay to post the main part of my script on here?